# Change printer default paper size

Tags: c#, printing, windows-7, windows-xp

I have several custom paper sizes defined on a printer(the printer is set as default). I need to be able to select one of these formats as the default one.

A programmatic(C#) solution would be ideal, but a command line one would be ok too.

Right now, I am able to get the list of paper sizes(name/dimensions) defined on the printer, and I can find out which one is the default.

In order to select another format as default, the only solution I have so far is by changing the **dmPaperSize** field on the **devMode** structure; BUT I cannot find out the correct value that corresponds to the desired paper format. So I set **dmPaperSize** to 0, and increment it, until the correct format appears on the printer. This takes a very long time on some printers.

Is there another way to select(by name) the default papaer format on the default printer ?

Comment: Did you try the solution I suggested?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are in the right direction in changing the default printer settings. .NET doesn't provide direct support to change the default settings of a printer.

I used the `PrinterSettings` class from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6899/Changing-printer-settings-using-C) codeproject article to change the printer settings.

The available paper sizes from the printer can be retrieved using the `PrintDocument.PrinterSettings`. See the sample code below for retrieving the available papersizes from the printer and using the `PaperSize.RawKind` for changing the papersize of the printer.

```
public class PrinterSettingsDlg : Form
{
    PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
    Button button1 = new Button();
    ComboBox combobox1 = new ComboBox();
    public PrinterSettingsDlg()
    {
        this.Load += new EventHandler(PrinterSettingsDlg_Load);
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
        this.Controls.Add(combobox1);
        button1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        button1.Text = "Change Printer Settings";
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        combobox1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrinterData pd = ps.GetPrinterSettings(PrinterName);
        pd.Size = ((PaperSize)combobox1.SelectedItem).RawKind;
        ps.ChangePrinterSetting(PrinterName, pd);
    }

    void PrinterSettingsDlg_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = // printer name
        combobox1.DisplayMember = "PaperName";
        foreach (PaperSize item in pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes)
        {
            combobox1.Items.Add(item);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: PaperSize.RawKind is exactly was I was looking for, Thank you!

Comment: Cannot find PrinterData class.

Comment: @digz6666 - Check the codeproject link for the class. Its just a example code snippet.

Comment: Not sure where you found `PrinterSettings.ChangePrinterSetting()` or `PrinterSettings.GetPrinterSettings()` methods, but they are not in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings_properties(v=vs.110).aspx   Is this some sort of special object / custom class ??

Comment: @SanuelJackson The `PrinterSettings` class is from the CodeProject article (link in answer) not from .NET framework.

Comment: Where is `PrinterData` class defined?

Comment: @Jack,  check the codeproject link for the class. Its just a example code snippet.

Comment: @Junaith I did check the code project and that couldn't find such class there.

Comment: I agree, `PrinterData` is not defined. It is also not in the codeproject class. But go into the discussion section and see this post on how to create the missing class: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6899/Changing-printer-settings-using-C?msg=5142354#xx5142354xx

Answer (score 6):

The following code would set the default printer papersize:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("PaperA4", 840, 1180);
pd.Print();
```

On how to print using PrintDocument you could refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although the question is about _selecting_ an existing format as default(not about printing), this code only works on some printers. BUT I am not trying to print, I want to change the _default_ _settings_ on the printer, so that when a document is sent(by any other program), the new format will be used.

Answer (score 0):

For me, This line gave a casting error from Devmode to PrinterData

```
PrinterData pd = ps.GetPrinterSettings(PrinterName);
```

So this is what I did instead of using that function.

```
string deviceToUse = "EPSON LQ-590II"; //Printer to look for
string paperToUse = "DOT MATRIX HALF"; //Page size to look for
int paperSizeRawKind = 0; //Variable for paper size
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();

//Iterate through all printers
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
   //Check if printer matches to what I want
   if (printer.Contains(deviceToUse))
   {
       //Iterate through all paper sizes for that printer
       for (int i = 0; i < printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; i++)
       {
          //Check if paper size matches what I want
          if (printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i].ToString().Contains(paperToUse))
          {
              //Set Paper Size RawKind here
              paperSizeRawKind = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i].RawKind;
           }
        }

        printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
        PrinterData printData = new PrinterData();

        printData.Size = paperSizeRawKind;
        ps.ChangePrinterSetting(printer, printData);
    }
}
```

This code is called in a button click event.