# C# Setting Default PrintDocument Size

Tags: c#

How can i set default Paper size to 6inch X 3inch. I tried the following code but printing A4.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
                PaperSize ps = new PaperSize("Custom", 440, 220);
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
                PageSettings pa = new PageSettings();
                pa.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = pa.Margins;
                pd.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
           // Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: check this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-custom-paper-sizes-to-named-printers

Comment: @KushalPatil Based on the link. How can i set my sizes? I want default size should be 6inchX3inch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can user `PrinterSettings`class from the below article:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/6899/changing-printer-settings-using-c

`PrintDocument.PrinterSettings` would give you available paper sizes from the printer.

Refer to the link below:

[Change printer default paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826507/change-printer-default-paper-size)